# toplink client session with server session

Tags: session, client-server, toplink

can i directly create unit of work on server session instead of creating multiple client session. As my application runs in multi threaded environment, so i am unable to get updated entity in some different client session so my application fails every now and then.. plz help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can acquire a UOW directly from a ServerSession.  But you may need to update your caching/locking/refreshing policies as the ClientSession does not have any caching.  Only the UOW and the ServerSession cache data.
If you have any more questions you should post on the EclipseLink User mailing list.
--Gordon Yorke